# Any way to access Yahoo! Mail if it is blocked?

Tags: yahoo-mail

A relative asked me this because access to Yahoo! Mail is disabled at work. I suggested that signing up Yahoo! Plus for $20/year to have POP3/SMTP access, then use Gmail or Outlook to access Yahoo!. However Gmail is also disabled. I was wondering if there is any workaround.

The last option would be to purchase an iPhone or Android smart phone and access his Yahoo! Mail via the wireless network.

I'm testing [Threadsy](http://www.threadsy.com/) and it looks really promising, even as a general purpose web email aggregator.

Comment: I understand it's an irony that Yahoo! Mail itself is a web app.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/bypass-corporate-firewall-for-im-closed

Comment: *please* see @eagle 's link . If Yahoo is disabled for work then the only option will be the iPhone on 3g or wifi, breaking work policy is not the reason/purpose for this site.

Comment: again, if the question would be "i need access to yahoo because my evil xyz .gov folks do not allow me to communicate with the free world" .. then this kind of question would be ok... the answer to this question is simply: "after a while the it guys will filter out the new webapp as well, just use a mobile phone." (and even THAT would be against some corporate policys, btw). so, please stop this hypocrisy and all this "it's illegal" and "leave that company" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [threadsy](http://www.threadsy.com/)

> threadsy is the world's first
>   integrated communication client. it
>   pulls together your existing email,
>   Facebook, Twitter, chat, and the
>   broader social web into a unique,
>   enjoyable experience.

Comment: I just tried. Threadsy doesn't require Yahoo! Plus (a huge plus). It worked really well with Chrome. However I had trouble sending email from my Yahoo account in Firefox and when I tried in IE8, it crashed. Regardless of aforementioned problems, it looks very promising. Thanks for this recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

There are several email web apps for getting pop3 & web mail. I use http://www.mail2web.com/ I don't know if it will work in this case, but I use it as a common interface for pop3 & web mail accounts.

Comment: I disabled all google email domain names on my own computer (mail.google.com, etc.) and tested on my computer and I was able to read gmail, however I had trouble sending email. Nonetheless this is probably the closest thing I have heard so far. +1 for this recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Quick reminder, that everyone seems to forget, but so-called "smart phones" aren't the only ones that can handle apps or email, they just do it better.

My previous phone, a six year old series 40 Nokia phone, can download and run GMail and Google Maps apps onto it, and has a POP3 and SMTP capable mail app. All very painful to use on a tiny screen with a T9 keyboard, but still possible if you just want to keep up to date on emails whilst at work.

Definitely worth looking into what your relative's current phone can do and whether Yahoo! already offer a native (or mobile Java) app for their phone.

*(have nothing against smartphones, currently use a Blackberry Bold and an Android HTC Magic, just hate the way everyone assumes you need a smart phone to do stuff I was doing on phones before the iPhone ever came out)*